# Output of "select 1 where NULL <> -1;"

Tags: sql

I guess I don't fully understand the meaning of NULL in SQL. I ran this SQL and I expected to see 1 as the output but I didn't see that:

```
select 1 where NULL <> -1;
```

Isn't NULL and -1 different? Can anyone explain why this clause of "NULL <> -1" is FALSE?

Comment: Basically, all comparisons other than `IS NULL` return either "false" or "NULL".  That is, they are never true and the rows are filtered out.

Comment: NULL Is not a value and therefore cannot be compared.

Comment: and thats why we state `something IS NULL` and not `something = NULL`

Comment: Any comparison with NULL results in an Unkown result, even `NULL = NULL` is not True.

Answer (score 0):

NULL Is not a value and therefore cannot be compared with any other value and get any other result than null. [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements005.htm). And [how](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1274000564279) to compare nulls.

Comment: I don't know what RDBMS the OP is using, but I don't think it's Oracle. Oracle shouldn't be accepting the OP's syntax, IIRC, it requires `from`.

Comment: @hvd: the explanation on how to deal with NULL values in expressions is still valid for any SQL dialect

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Generally yes, but the linked documentation contains Oracle-specific details as well, at least the warning about zero-length strings and the mention of some non-standard functions. That won't be useful to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` means unknown. So with `where NULL <> -1` you want to know whether the unknown value equals -1. The DBMS does not know (of course), so the result of the expression is neither `TRUE` nor `FALSE`; it is `NULL`.

Only rows for which the `WHERE` clause results in `TRUE` are selected. As your expression doesn't result in `TRUE` but in `NULL`, there is no row selected.

Comment: In fact the result of a comparison with NULL results in UNKNOWN, not NULL.

Comment: @dnoeth: No, NULL *is* the database name for unknown. Try `select 1 where (null = -1) is null`. (Here is a test on PostgreSQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/11585.)

Comment: A column can be `NULL`, but never the result of a comparison, that's why there's `IS UNKNOWN` in Standard SQL (and PostgreSQL, too). See the pages around https://books.google.de/books?id=efe2wB_DfxYC&pg=PA219&lpg=PA219&dq=%22Truth+table+for+the+AND+boolean+operator%22&source=bl&ots=DfT9W4xLGF&sig=Yee-tSw5oQjTfoazWtRYEzuXBMM&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQ6ICmrpfPAhWBpiwKHVNQBo0Q6AEIJTAB#v=onepage&q=%22Truth%20table%20for%20the%20AND%20boolean%20operator%22&f=false

Comment: @dnoeth: Thank you, I didn't know that. What I knew was that an expression results in a value, for instance in a string value (e.g. a || b) or a numeric value (e.g. a + b) or a boolean value (e.g. a or b). I didn't know that the boolean datatype is thus supposed to hold either `TRUE` or `FALSE` or `UNKNOWN`; I thought it were `TRUE` or `FALSE` or `NULL`. But I've read it up in a SQL 2003 draft; and it shows that it really shall be `UNKNOWN`, but it is allowed for a DBMS to use `NULL` instead. I suppose that `UNKNOWN` is supposed to behave exactly like `NULL` anyway.